# error about using ifstream in loop

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a very simple code and the functionality of it is to type in the name of the file from which the program will read data. Since the file might not be correct due to mistyping, the console will continue to ask the user to type in the name if the previous name is invalid.

The issue is, while the first do-while loop works fine, the program will skip the second while loop if the name of the file is not correctly typed in for the first time in the first loop. However, if the name of the file is typed in correctly, everything works fine.

I wonder why the program behaves like this.

Thanks for your help and your time!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string context;
    int step=0,i=0;
    ifstream fin;

    do {
        string filename;
        cout << endl << "please type in the name of input file" << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        string filepath = "files/" + filename;
        cout << filepath << endl;
        fin.open( filepath.c_str() );
    } while( !fin.is_open() );

    while (getline(fin, context)){
        cout << context << endl;
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the state of "fin" might be tainted after the first try.
Why dont you try calling fin.clear() before the call to fin.open().

Comment: Not just *might* be tainted. The correct word is *is*. The standard mandates that a successful call to `open` will not change the error state. If it was already "bad", it will remain bad. So `clear` it first.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to clear your ifstream, it could be corrupted by the previous file attempt.

Answer (score 1):

From the standard,

> 27.8.1.10
>   `void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`
>   Calls `rdbuf()->open(s,mode|out)`. If that function returns a null pointer, calls
>   setstate(failbit).<sup>311a</sup>

So what's this note 311a?

> <sup>311a</sup> A successful open does not change the error state.

While notes are not normative, the normative text says absolutely nothing about what a successful open does to the error state if the `rdbuf->open()` was successful. The note clarifies this non-statement.

Bottom line: You need to `clear` the file stream's status bits prior to calling `open` when you are re-calling `open` after it failed.